# Ambiguous deduction in SFINAE template constructor in clang++, not g++

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, clang++, sfinae

The following example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct X {
    static constexpr bool B = std::is_same_v<T, int>;
    
    template <bool Z = B, std::enable_if_t<Z, int> = 0>
    X(T t) { std::cout << t << " - int\n"; }
    
    template <bool Z = B, std::enable_if_t<!Z, int> = 0>
    X(T t) { std::cout << t << " - not int\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    X x(5);
    
    X y(5.0);
}
```

Results in an ambiguous deduction error when compiled using clang++ (I tried up to 11.0) with `-std=c++1z`. Compilation terminates successfully with g++ 9.3.0.

Who is right? Why? Is there a bug associated with this?

Comment: You might add custom deduction guide [`template <typename T> X(T) -> X<T>;
`](https://godbolt.org/z/Mf83hc).

Comment: @Jarod42 This seems to work also in my non-MWE use case, thanks! Since the question still stands, I'll leave it here anyway.

Comment: If you use `std::is_same_v<T, int>` directly instead of `B`, Clang is appeased. I'm guessing it's a chicken and egg problem for Clang. The value-dependent member `B` of a specialization is required to deduce the specialization itself. When you avoid using `B`, the compiler-generated deduction guide(s) will do just fine.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Not with `requires` though [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TfKTzd).

Comment: @Jarod42 - The normative text doesn't carry constraints over to compiler generated deduction guides (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.class.deduct#1.1). I wonder if it's a defect or there's a deeper meaning here.